# EF Core 2.2 Enable SQL-Server Change Tracking

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

we use `EF-Core 2.2` Code first approach to generate our Database. When the DB is created I would like to activate the Change Tracking feature of the SQL-Server.

But I havent't found an option to send an SQL-Command via EF or an option to configure this. How can I do it?

Comment: Use the migration builder.Sql() method to add the ALTER statements

Comment: But how can I ensure that the Statement is only run once after the Database is created and not on every migration?

Comment: Add a conditional check to the SQL script, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182085/how-to-check-if-change-tracking-is-enabled-on-a-specific-table